# What arithmetic information is determined by the $j$-invariant of an elliptic curve?

Tags: elliptic-curves

It is known that the complex isomorphism class of an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{C}$ is uniquely determined by its $j$-invariant. One way to define it algebraically for a curve

$$\displaystyle E : y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B, A,B \in \mathbb{C}$$

is by

$$j(E) = 1728 \cdot \frac{4A^3}{4A^3 + 27B^2}.$$

Of course $j$ is also a modular function, and can be expressed as $j(\tau)$, where $\tau$ is a complex number such that $E/\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C}/\langle 1, \tau \rangle$. By reduction theory, we can further assume that $\tau$ is in the Gauss fundamental domain in the upper half-plane: that is, we may assume that $|\Re(\tau)| \leq 1/2$ and $\Im(\tau) \geq 1$.

If we assume that $A,B \in \mathbb{Z}$ (or more generally, simply algebraic integers), then we can attach a *modular height* to the elliptic curve by simply evaluating the Weil height (as an algebraic number) of the $j$-invariant of $E$, say $h(j(E))$.

When $\gcd(A,B) = 1$, then $h(j(E))$ is typically close to the so-called naive height of $E$, namely $H(E_{A,B}) = \max\{4|A|^3, 27B^2\}$. However, there are cases when the two heights differ significantly.

Another way to measure the size of $j(E)$ with $E$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ is to simply take its absolute value. In this case, we see that if we expect $4A^3$ and $4A^3 + 27B^2$ to be roughly the same size, then $|j(E)|$ is typically very small.

Therefore, elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ whose $j$-invariants have very large absolute value are exceptional, as they correspond to those curves whose discriminants are very small compared to the naive height of the curve.

My question is, what arithmetic information can one glean from a curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$ with $\gcd(A,B) = 1$ (or more generally, taking a minimal element in the twist family) whose $j$-invariant has very large absolute value? Alternatively, such an elliptic curve has a period $\tau$ in the fundamental domain with large imaginary part.

Comment: Why not choosing $y^2= 4x^3-27j/(j-1728)x-27j/(j-1728)$, the arithmetic complexity is about  how it differs from the integer equation with minimal discriminant

Comment: It is more cautious to talk about what arithmetic information one can gain for the family of (quadratic) twists of elliptic curves $E/\mathbb{Q}$ with that $j$-invariant. Or do you choose one curve in that family?

Comment: In the $p$-adic version, large $\vert j(E)\vert _p$ measures if $E$ has potential multiplicative reduction and how many components it has.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich you are right of course; I had this in mind when I insisted that $\gcd(A,B) = 1$, but ultimately the wording of the question did not make this clear. I will edit the question

Comment: Roughly speaking, large $|j|_p$ means that $E$ has "highly" multiplicative reduction at $p$ (and thus it's Neron polygon has lots of sides). So large $|j|_\infty$ means that $E$ has "highly multiplicative reduction at the infinite place of $\mathbb Q$." One can feed that into various machines to get information. For example, Lang's height lower bound conjecture $\hat h(P)\gg\log|\Delta|$ is true, I think. Is that the sort of thing that you had in mind?

Comment: @JoeSilverman everything you wrote in your comment is very interesting to me... do you have references for the phenomena you mentioned?

Comment: Which phenomena? The $p$-adic fact is standard, the number of components on the Neron model is the valuation of the discriminant. The height result probably isn't written down anywhere, and I'm not 100% sure it's correct; but if it is, it should follow from the methods in my 1981 *Duke Math J* paper, since one can pigeon-hole to get $\hat h(P)$ larger than a multiple of $\log|j|$, and if $|j|$ is big enough, that will overwhelm the worst possible contribution of $-\frac1{24}\log\Delta$ coming from the finite places. If you have an application ,I could work it out more carefully.

Comment: @JoeSilverman perhaps it is better I send you an email explaining the exact question I am interested in, as I think the comment box is not large enough for that